# REGEX for Allow all extension's files in PHP project not folder

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I just want to know that what regex I use for allowing access  all files of a folder. I'm using following expression in .htaccess file but here I have to add each extension that I want to allow...

```
<Files ~ "^index\.php|css|js|.*\.png|.*\.jpg|.*\.gif|.*\.svg|.*\.docx|.*\.pdf|.*\.rar|.*\.zip|.*\.mp4">
     Allow from all
</Files>
```

I want a single expression...

Can anyone help me out...

Thanks

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the .htaccess syntax but would a simple `.*\..*` pattern work?

Comment: Thanks... Its working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution...

Thanks to [Lambda Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2397327/lambda-ninja)

```
<Files ~ "^index\.php|css|js|.*\..*">
     Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Even if the proposed solution is not good. Because it is not useful to indicate `^index\.php|css|js|` which all correspond to `.+\..+` !

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<Files ~ ".+\..+">
     Allow from all
</Files>
```